# Not able to write in inputbox of Google's homepage by WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gs_htif0']"))
            .sendKeys("selenium");
```

I want to send to use xpath as a locater.
Error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled
>   and so may not be used for actions Command duration or timeout: 75
>   milliseconds

After that I want to get the google suggestions printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the google search bar by ID, try this id: //*[@id='lst-ib']

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gs_htif0']"))
            .sendKeys("selenium");
```

You can also try these:

```
python: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='q']").send_keys('selenium')
java: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='q']")).sendKeys("selenium");
```

---

To get the suggestions you can try this:

```
  List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='option']"));
            for (int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(rows.get(i).getText());
            }
```

> Output:
>  selenium
>  selenium ide
>  selenium tutorial
>  selenium webdriver

Comment: But what i need is to handle the Ajax. this could be possible by id only as it is changing every time. and //*[@id='gs_htif0'] the Xpath of input box it is not changing every time.after this for all the suggestions its is changing like //*[@id='gs_htif1'],//*[@id='gs_htif2']

Comment: @DJ developer - your first question was that - you were not able to write into the input box. Which can be solved by either using the correct id or name. You commented that it worked! Your frequent edit/remove comments made things confusing :)

Comment: sorry @chandan  , Yes it worked as i was able to write into the input box. but  it will not work when i want to work with something called 'AJAX'.Do you have any solution for this? the above code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DJ developer, what is the scenario that you are trying to do? A new question with appropriate information will be the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using name instead of XPATH. Name selector is faster than Xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First click in the input box and then use . sendKeys("whatever you want to type ")